# Properties of a dynamic variable of a movieclip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movieclip

I do occasionally use this useful property of the flash.display.MovieClip class

for eg:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc["myVariable"] = myAnotherMovieClip;
mc["myVariable2"] = true;
mc["myVariable3"] = new Array(0,0,1);
```

Well, I'd like to learn more about this 'feature' of movieclip. As I got to know this from a colleague and do not really know as to what this is called in AS3.

I'd be really glad if you people could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS3, the MovieClip class is a dynamic class. More informations here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#dynamic

Comment: +1: Thank you for the link which gave me what I wanted to know. I'm marking this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The movie clip class is a dynamic object and it can hold different types of variables (properties). Square brackets are a way of dynamically setting and accessing the properties of an object.

`trace(mc["myVariable2"])` would output `true`;

`trace(mc.myVariable2)` would output `true` as well.

Note that `mc["myVariable"] = myAnotherMovieClip` would create a property that stores the reference to myAnotherMovieClip.